# How to change the value of each elmement in vector using iterator in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I wrote the following program to initialize a `vector` of `Person`. But the `id` of the `Person` objects does not change. This really confuses me. Can somebody give me an explanation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<Person>* pv = new vector<Person>(5,Person(0));
    int i = 0;
    for(Person person : *pv)
    {
        person.id = i++;
    }

    for(Person person : *pv)
    {
        cout<< person.id << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with `person.h` like this

```
#include <string>

class Person
{
  public:
    int id;
    std::string name;
    Person(int d);
};
```

Comment: I would think you need to iterate with for(Person& person : *pv)? I think you're changing the id of a copy. If you iterate by reference you should change the id of the object in the vector.

Comment: ok I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Your shown example has absolutely no need for pointers or `new`, by the way.

Comment: ... and there's no matching `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop you need to iterate by reference or you will be assigning to the id of a copy of the Person in the vector, not the actual Person in the vector.

```
for(Person& person : *pv)
{
    person.id = i++;
}
```